# How to setup SSH tunneling in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a RDS instance with mysql database and which can only be accessed by an ec2 instance running in AWS. Now i want to access my RDS instance from local machine using SSH tunneling. I searched a lot on the net but none of the solutions worked. Can any one please tell me how to do it step by step with working solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

I tried to run -

ssh -i myNewKey.pem -N -L 3306:myredinstance:3306 ec2-user@myec2-instance.

mysql -u dbauser -p -h 127.0.0.1 on mysql-js utility and it gave me error. Please see below :-
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by setting up a ssh tunel

```
ssh -i /path/to/key -N -L 3306:an_rds_endpoint:3306 user@yourserver.com
```

Then connect locally

```
mysql -u myuser -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: if i run this - ssh -N -L 3306:an_rds_endpoint:3306 user@yourserver.com         . I am getting Permission denied (publickey) . I think i also need to specify the private key required to connect to the ec2-instance?

Comment: the specify your ec2 key
ssh  -i /path/to/key -N -L 3306:an_rds_endpoint:3306 user@yourserver.com

Comment: I am getting error while running the mysql command. Please see the screen shot attached.

Comment: First make sure the tunnel is successful. It seems the problem has to do with not switching to the sql mode